# How can I reproduce this design in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

[image]

I am reasonably sure that this was made in Premiere Pro, as the video in which I found this had individual tiles "fly in." Is there an easy and quick way to do this tile effect on a still photograph? I just like this photo effect and I want to make a different photo out of tiles.

Comment: If you lay out a grid of guides you can export tiles as slices, then reimport all the slices, and then recompose the image using the tiles each on its own layer. Then, manually move the tiles around. The center of the image has the tiles offset slightly, and the father away from center, the wider the gaps. The base layer is probably a flood fill of a color slightly lighter than the lightest color present in the original. Then randomly fuss with the levels for each tile. Roll a 6-sided die and then adjust that tile: 1 => lighten 20%; 2 => lighten 10%; 3 do nothing, 4 => darken 10% etc.

Comment: @Yorik. Please put that in the answer field :) In all seriousness, please avoid answering questions in the comments, even if your answer is barely long enough to reach the character limit. Qs that get their answer in a comment tend to get abandoned by the asker, never getting an 'accepted' answer. Which hurts site stats and credibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to achieve this effect here is how i would go about doing it.

- First of all open up your image in Photoshop, and duplicate the layer.
- Take the bottom layer and add a Blur (Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur)
- Go Back to the top layer the duplicated one.
- Create a grid layout using Rulers ( View > Rulers )
- Once you have your grid made take the Rectangle Marquee tool <kbd>Press M</kbd> and draw between the grid lines the box you desire. See below for an example:

[image]

- Now all you have to do is hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to copy then <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd> to paste and it should post each block into a new layer, make sure your on the duplicated picture layer every time your copying and pasting.
- Once you have all the blocks in separate layers you can simply move them around as desired, some slightly up, down, left or right.

[image]

- Little tip is to remove your Rulers when positioning the blocks so you can see better the final outcome.